# property 'border:none' doesn't work well in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, safari

**I'm having some problems to apply the property 'border:none' in the safari browser.**
I've tried to apply a css class named 'profile-label', that has a property 'border:none' into a tag 'label', like in the code bellow:

```css
.profile-label {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="photo" class="profile-label" type="submit">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Foto" width="50" height="50" class="profile-photo" /> 
     <input type="file" id="photo" hidden  name="ProfileImage"/>
</label>
```

**That property doesn't work properly in safari (border: none), however works well in all others browsers.  Does anyone know why?**

Image with border in safari browzer:

[image]

Comment: Please also share the CSS for the "profile-photo" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing a button border because of the label wraping the image with a type="submit" attribute.

Safari is adding the default style of all buttons.

Try adding `-webkit-appearance: none`; to your label style

Or remove the attribute `type=submit`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding the following property to your CSS:

```
outline: none;
```

Not sure I could answer why that happens, though.

Comment: thank you, I've already tried that, but the 'outline:none' doesn't work in Safari either.

Comment: Just reproduced the case locally and couldn't see any of the issues. Have you tried the solutions contained here? https://medium.com/@ricardozea/how-to-remove-the-blue-border-outline-in-chrome-safari-and-dotted-line-in-firefox-edge-fe5e2155d44c